# Python: Copying certain columns to an empty dataframe using For loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
wo = "C:/temp/temp/WO.xlsx"
dfwo = pd.read_excel(wo)

columnnames = ["TicketID","CreateDate","Status","Summary","CreatedBy","Company"]
main = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnnames)

for i in range(0,15):
    print(i)
    main["TicketID"][i] = dfwo["WO ID"][i]
    main["CreateDate"][i] = dfwo["WO Create TimeStamp"][i]
    main["Status"][i] = dfwo["Status"][i]
    main["Summary"][i] = dfwo["WO Summary"][i]
    main["CreatedBy"][i] = dfwo["Submitter Full Name"][i]
    main["Company"][i] = dfwo["Company"][i]
```

I am trying to copy selected columns from 1 df to another.
dfwo is a df derived from Excel
Main is an empty dataframe and has selected columns from dfwo

When I run this code, it gives me the error, "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Any suggestions pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wo = "C:/temp/temp/WO.xlsx"
dfwo = pd.read_excel(wo)

columnnames =["TicketID","CreateDate","Status","Summary","CreatedBy","Company"]
main = dfwo[columnnames]
new_col_names =  {
    "TicketID":"WO ID",
    "CreateDate":"WO Create TimeStamp",
    "Status":"Status",
    "Summary":"WO Summary",
    "CreatedBy":"Submitter Full Name",
    "Company":"Company"
}
main.rename(columns = new_col_names,inplace = True)
```

Comment: Column names in dfwo are not same. I cant keep the names of columns in Main same as dfwo as I plan to combine more df data into Main later.

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty. However, do you know what was wrong with the For loop approach?